# Como insertar datos en tablas pivot?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, poo, mvc

**Tengo las siguietentes tablas:**
-> Relacion M:M utilizo DB: MySQL y PHP, ningun otro leguaje

```
**Persona** 
-id 
-nombre

**persona_hospital** 
-id 
-id_persona 
-id_hospital

**hospital** 
-id 
-nombre
```

**Preguntas:**
-> Como puedo insertar el "id" en los fk, en otras palabras como insertar los id de relacion en la tabla pivot?. Los datos son enviados desde un formularion a la bd, el id "pk" de cada tabla es auto incremental por lo que no tengo que asignar el valor en la sentencia insert de la consulta sql.

-> lo que pienso es que debo insertar primero los datos del formulario en la base de datos, luego realizar una consulta que obtenga el id del dato insertado en las tablas persona/hospital, despues de esto utilizar estas consultas para asignar los id a la tabla pivot persona_hospital. lo que pienso no es optimo.

> Aclaro que soy nuevo en esto de php y doy muchas gracias de antemano a
> los que aporten sus repuestas y comentarios.

Comment: Agrega el código de las inserciones para que te indiquemos cómo puedes obtener los ids.

Comment: Te falta mostrar qué estás intentando hacer en PHP y por qué no funciona :) Puedes [edit] todo lo que quieras la pregunta para ampliar la info y que podamos responderte

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para insertar los datos en la tabla pivote, primero debes insertar los datos en las tablas persona y hospital y luego obtener los IDs de los registros insertados. Una vez que tienes los IDs, puedes utilizarlos para insertar los datos en la tabla pivote persona_hospital.

Por ejemplo, si quieres insertar los datos en las tablas persona y hospital, y luego insertar los IDs en la tabla pivote persona_hospital, puedes utilizar las siguientes consultas SQL:

```
-- Inserta los datos en la tabla persona
INSERT INTO persona (nombre)
VALUES ('Juan');

-- Inserta los datos en la tabla hospital
INSERT INTO hospital (nombre)
VALUES ('Hospital General');

-- Obtiene el ID del registro insertado en la tabla persona
SELECT id FROM persona WHERE nombre = 'Juan';

-- Obtiene el ID del registro insertado en la tabla hospital
SELECT id FROM hospital WHERE nombre = 'Hospital General';

-- Inserta los IDs en la tabla pivote persona_hospital
INSERT INTO persona_hospital (id_persona, id_hospital)
VALUES (1, 1);
```

En este ejemplo, se insertan los datos en las tablas persona y hospital, y luego se utilizan las consultas SELECT para obtener los IDs de los registros insertados. Finalmente, se insertan los IDs en la tabla pivote persona_hospital.

También puedes utilizar la función LAST_INSERT_ID() de MySQL para obtener el ID del último registro insertado en una tabla. Por ejemplo, en lugar de utilizar las consultas SELECT para obtener los IDs, puedes utilizar la siguiente consulta:

```
-- Inserta los IDs en la tabla pivote persona_hospital
INSERT INTO persona_hospital (id_persona, id_hospital)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

Esta consulta insertará los IDs del último registro insertado en las tablas persona y hospital en la tabla pivote persona_hospital.

En resumen, para insertar los datos en la tabla pivote, primero debes insertar los datos en las tablas relacionadas y luego obtener los IDs de los registros insertados. Una vez que tienes los IDs, puedes utilizarlos para insertar los datos en la tabla pivote. Puedes utilizar consultas SELECT o la función LAST_INSERT_ID() para obtener los IDs de los registros insertados.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5450/cheatgpt-chatgpt-nos-ha-alcanzado-en-soes  De paso, evita resonder a preguntas incompletas.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, la verdad me ayudaste mucho.